# How to fetch data from multiple table in springboot without join Query?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two tables (Leave, CompOff) I want to show these tables data to user(frontend) in form of Requests from employee. Employee can request for leave and compoff. Both the tables have createdOn, empid column. And I am not understanding how to fetch both table data and then return a list which contain both the tables data.

Leave tables -

```
empid      |       ceated_on

   1       |      09-07-2022
   2       |      05-07-2022
   3       |      02-07-2022
```

CompOff tables -

```
empid      |       ceated_on

   1       |      08-07-2022
   2       |      06-07-2022
   3       |      01-07-2022
```

In Springboot I have created three classes name - leave, compoff, request. And they have some create/update opertaion. Now in request class I want both (leave,compoff) data and send to user.

Comment: What does this problem have to do with spring boot? Isn't this purely an SQL question?

Comment: @Bohemian As I was making this project in springboot, I thought there might be someone who can tell me other ways to fetch data from two repository and combine them into one list and return in @ service class

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *union* not a *join*.

Create a native query something like:

```
select 'leave' as type, empid, created_on, <other columns>
from leave
union all
select 'compoff', empid, created_on, <same other columns as above>
from compoff
```